# PHP MongoDB performance drop

Tags: php, mongodb, performance, openshift

Good day, first of all thanks in advance for providing any guidance.

Recently I started having problems with a service I run which is giving 503 errors during peak hours. I run the service in a PHP(5.4) / MongoDB(2.4) powered API. Attached next the mongostat and mongotop during the peak hour latency.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The timestamps on mongostat and mongotop are not quite at the same timeframe but they did occur during the same downtime period and I would consider safe to assume that it is a valid representation.

The platform is hosted in Openshift (both web server and database).

What I find curious is the amount of connections and (qr|ar) vs the amount of queries that are being performed. Taking into consideration that the use of the indexing is optimal in this case (idx miss % is zero?).

I may be missinterpreting the output but where could be the problem be? the php mongodb driver and the amount of connections opened?. Flaws in the source code of the php application?

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? what would be the best course of action?

I was thinking on increasing the max connections allowed but MongoDB default seems higher and I don't think it would help. I'm also clueless as how to tackle high amount of  clients queued for reading and the peak of high active reads when the amount of queries performed are way lower.

Thank you again.

Comment: are you using Oplog?

Comment: No, we are not using oplog. The database is not sharded nor replicated either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a bad index problem. If you check mongostat on top you will see that for 1-100 queries done per second we had over 400 connections opened and there was a huge qr  requests. By checking the queries related to the most used collections (check mongotop) we found out that in our push_notifications collection there was query that was being indexed by the wrong value. The php mongo driver for some reason (still unknown) started creating connections and queries were queued, memory reached peak and system overall became slow.

After fixing the code and reordering the fields of the query in the code and inserting proper index in the database we started seeing better performance and no connections overflow.

**Conclusion**: while in PHP use mongostat and mongotop to analyze what are the most used collections, check your code and try to optimize the indexes and the order of the fields for querying.